# Clicking a button on a web site

Tags: vba

I am trying to build a VBA code to visit a website, input email address and password and click "log in" button. I have reached to the point email address and password is inputted, just not able to complete the code for hitting send button.

Below is the core code for VBA:

```
Function LogintoWebsite(uid As String, password As String) As Boolean

    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim useridF1d As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement    'email
    Dim passwordFld As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement  'password
    Dim SinginBt As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement 'signin
    
    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    objIE.navigate URLstr
    
    Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    
        Set ieDoc = objIE.document
        objIE.Visible = True
        
            Set useridF1d = ieDoc.all.Item("email")
            useridF1d.Value = uid
            Set passwordFld = ieDoc.all.Item("password")
            passwordFld.Value = password
            Set SinginBt = ieDoc.all.Item("btn btn-primary m-t-2 btn-block") 'all.Item("btn btn-primary m-t-2 btn-block")
            SinginBt.Click
            
            Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Loop
            LogintoTransferwise = True
            
        Set objIE = Nothing
        
        Exit Function
```

And below is the HTML Element for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary m-t-2 btn-block" type="submit">
```

Comment: So what is the issue you're facing? If any, what error are you getting?

Comment: There are better methods available than `document.all` to access elements in the HTML page.  `getElementsByClassName()` might be a good place to start.

Comment: You're using multiple class names (separated by space). Choose one of them. A better way to do this is to work out the action (url) the submit button is going to and navigate to that url directly. (The action might be defined in the <form> tag

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you please confirm the complete syntax to use getElementsByClassName() and if it would work with Dim SinginBt As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Comment: @SuperSymmetry when I use Debug and reach the code SinginBy.Click I get error Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @SuperSymmetry the <form> tag comprises of all the fields like email address, password and login button. There is no specific <form> tag for just the button.

Comment: You should have something like `<form action="example_action">`. Once you fill in the email and password fields simply navigate to `url/example_action`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry is there any way to search the complete element list of a website to search for "form action". I brushed through the website using "Inspect element" and couldn't find anything like form action for the button.

Comment: What is the complete button html? should be in the format `<button ....>.....</button>` (as you may know)

Comment: @SuperSymmetry <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-2 btn-block"><div><span class="tw-icon tw-icon-lock pull-left" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><svg width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M11 17v-3h2v3h-2z"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12 1a6.5 6.5 0 00-6.5 6.5V9H3v10a3 3 0 003 3h12a3 3 0 003-3V9h-2.5V7.5A6.5 6.5 0 0012 1zm4.5 8V7.5a4.5 4.5 0 10-9 0V9h9zM5 11v8a1 1 0 001 1h12a1 1 0 001-1v-8H5z"></path></svg></span>Log in<span class="pull-right btn-loader invisible"></span></div></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```vb
  Dim btn As Object
  For Each btn In ieDoc.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    If InStr(1, btn.InnerText, "Log in", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      btn.Click
      Exit For
    End If
  Next btn
```

in place of the lines

```vb
            Set SinginBt = ieDoc.all.Item("btn btn-primary m-t-2 btn-block") 'all.Item("btn btn-primary m-t-2 btn-block")
            SinginBt.Click
```

**(Not Tested)**